# A Dropbox-like open source WebDAV sync client for Windows, written in C/C++/C#

Tags: windows, open-source, c#, c, webdav

I'm looking for something like ownCloud Client - a background app which syncs local folder with remove WebDAV storage accompanied with a desktop tool which has Dropbox-like UI (such as an icon in Windows system tray to control the software).

ownCloud Client didn't work for me because:
- its Windows version needs to be compiled on Linux (not suitable for me)
- it's not pure WebDAV, you cannot directly specify a WebDAV URL in it, the client requires ownCloud server particularly, not just any WebDAV server. I think this can be worked around with tweaking the software but the previous point with Linux development is currently a showstopper.

Other alternatives I tried (pydio, syncany, etc) are either not WebDAV sync (their server part can support WebDAV but their clients are not WebDAV) or written in Java (not C/C++/C#), or they are not doing sync but only establishing connection to a WebDAV drive (like in Windows Explorer).

Maybe I'm missing some good project which does what I need? Please note that I don't need any server part, the WebDAV server is already set up.

Comment: Most O/S have means to mount WebDAV storage as a network drive or folder. So, somewhat indirectly, every program that can sync local folders could be used. Mind you, however, that reliable automatic two-way sync'ing is non-trivial (and hard to find).